# How to generate possible arragment of two or more different designed tiles using c# /jquery/javascript/silverlight?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to figure out what the best way would be to set up a interface of multiple 'tiles' (a variable background image, and text on it.) that acts as the hub of the interface.

I want to generate possible arrangement of two or more different tiles in such a way that it looks a design. 

Two or more tiles (div blocks) having different backgrounds. How to generate it in rows and columns.

 how it possible using C# or jquery..

Here is a screen shot of two different tiles(box)
 [image]

if it possible in Silverlight version that also acceptable as answer

Comment: Its not really clear what you want here - it sounds like you might want text floating in front of a tiled background, if so then tiling divs for the background is not the best way to go.  Better to repeat a background image that consists of 2 red and 2 blue squares - then simply put text in as normal.  If it is a requirement that you use divs in the background for some reason then that is another story.

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery, or in C#, you just need a for loop creating HTML elements and adding a class to every second one. This would work best with floating, fixed width <li> elements inside a <ul>

For example, in C#

```
string html = "";
bool red = false;
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
    red = !red;
    if(red==true)
        html += "<li class='red'></li>";
    else
        html += "<li></li>";
}
html = "<ul class='blocks'>" + html + "</ul>";
```

the CSS would be something like

```
.blocks li { width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; background: blue; }
.blocks li.red { background: red; }
```

Comment: thanks @roryok , you reply for only two different colored boxes. but if I have more than 2 then . How I do that..?  In case there are three boxes or more than How we can arrange with different styles?

Comment: can u gave me solution for more than 2 block arrangments..?

Comment: anymore than 2 colours and you wouldn't get a chessboard pattern... however if you wanted to do that, you'd just replace the bool red = false with a number, say n. if n == 1, then red if n == 2 then blue if n == 3 then green etc

then at the end of your for loop, if (n < [number of colours]) n ++ else n = 1; that'll keep the n value from going above the number of colours

Comment: @royok for that I need replace your condition. and dynamic for loop as per no of colors.. for example if I 3 colored box then I need add one more for loop for other ones right!...